# Can't Access sys/socket.h using Cygwin

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, cygwin, mingw

I need to compile C/C++ pthread and socket code in windows 8 where I've installed MicGW GCC and G++ 4.7.
When I compile my test code using `g++ test.cpp -o test`

**Code is:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
     cout<<"Got Socket";
}
```

This gives error `fatal error: sys/socket.h not found` and the
same occur with `types.h`

The error I found is that cygwin is using MicGW GCC and g++ but I want it to use its own instead of MinGW's so that I can include Linux libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to reproduce your problem on my Cygwin.

Are the headers present in /usr/include/sys?

Comment: Yes they are. But what I observed its not compiling cpp/c files using libraries using the headers present in /usr/include/sys? but its doing so using the headers at C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.7.0

Comment: Maybe it is not using the right compiler? Try "which g++" to see which one it uses. You can also specify the include path with the -I parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Search the `sys` folder in `[installed directory]/usr/include` if the `socket.h` was not there download one Copy it there manually.

don't afraid of manual works ;-)